# How to fake petite caps?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, small-caps

How are petite caps faked when the font only has small caps?  By petite caps is meant small capitals that are slightly higher than the x-height of the font.  In the MWE below, the petite caps are good but capital letters inside the `\textsc{}` are stretched out and too high.

Can the method below be modified to not affect capital letters? or is there any other method to obtain petite caps?

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,FakeStretch=0.8,Scale=1.25,LetterSpace=4}]{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
A\textsc{Abcd}s
\end{document}
```

Comment: In fonts with real petite caps, it’s the small caps that are (usually) slightly taller than the x-height, whereas the petite caps are *shorter* than the x-height.  See, for example, FF Tibere.  Please don’t fake petite caps: the result would be ugly.

Comment: @Thérèse With the definition you give, it is small caps I am after.  I would not fake font features, if I did not have to.

Comment: tugboat uses "stepped-down" regular caps for acronyms since we find the default small caps *too* small.  the mechanism is a bit complicated, but the idea can be adapted.  look for the `\acro` definition in `ltugboat.cls` (in tex live or on ctan).  the input does have to be all uppercase the way it's defined there, so simply using ordinary mixed-case input won't work.